# Pandas: how to select rows in data frame based on condition of a specific value on a specific column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a given data frame as below example:

```
            0  1      2      3      4      5        6        7        8  
0      842517  M  20.57  17.77  132.9   1326  0.08474  0.07864   0.0869   
1    84300903  M  19.69  21.25    130   1203   0.1096   0.1599   0.1974   
2    84348301  M  11.42  20.38  77.58  386.1   0.1425   0.2839   0.2414   
3      843786  M  12.45   15.7  82.57  477.1   0.1278     0.17   0.1578   
4      844359  M  18.25  19.98  119.6   1040  0.09463    0.109   0.1127
```

And I wrote a function that should split the dataset into 2 data frames, based on comparison of a value in a specific column and a specific value.
For example, if I have `col_idx = 2` and `value=18.3` the result should be:

df1 - below the value:

```
            0  1      2      3      4      5        6        7        8    
2    84348301  M  11.42  20.38  77.58  386.1   0.1425   0.2839   0.2414   
3      843786  M  12.45   15.7  82.57  477.1   0.1278     0.17   0.1578   
4      844359  M  18.25  19.98  119.6   1040  0.09463    0.109   0.1127
```

df2 - above the value:

```
            0  1      2      3      4      5        6        7        8  
0      842517  M  20.57  17.77  132.9   1326  0.08474  0.07864   0.0869   
1    84300903  M  19.69  21.25    130   1203   0.1096   0.1599   0.1974
```

The function should look like:

```
def split_dataset(data_set, col_idx, value):
    below_df = ?
    above_df = ?
    return below_df, above_df
```

Can anybody complete my script please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
below_df = data_set[data_set[col_idx] < value]
above_df = data_set[data_set[col_idx] > value]  # you have to deal with data_set[col_idx] == value though
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `loc`:

```
def split_dataset(data_set, col_idx, value):
    below_df = df.loc[df[col_idx]<=value]
    above_df = df.loc[df[col_idx]>=value]
    return below_df, above_df
df1,df2=split_dataset(df,'2',18.3)
```

> Output:

```
df1

          0  1      2      3       4       5        6       7       8
2  84348301  M  11.42  20.38   77.58   386.1  0.14250  0.2839  0.2414
3    843786  M  12.45  15.70   82.57   477.1  0.12780  0.1700  0.1578
4    844359  M  18.25  19.98  119.60  1040.0  0.09463  0.1090  0.1127
```

---

```
df2
          0  1      2      3      4       5        6        7       8
0    842517  M  20.57  17.77  132.9  1326.0  0.08474  0.07864  0.0869
1  84300903  M  19.69  21.25  130.0  1203.0  0.10960  0.15990  0.1974
```

---

**Note:**

Note that in this function call the names of the columns are numbers. You have to know before calling the function the correct type of columns. You may have to use `string` type or not.

---

You should also define what happens if the value with which the data frame is divided (value) is included in the column of the data frame.